# IdentityServer4 - How to Call One ApiResource from Another ApiResource

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a spa application setup that is protected with IdentityServer4 using the Hybrid Authorization flow with OpenId Connect.

This spa application is able to call multiple ApiResources, as the logged in user, by requesting the access_token via

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

This is working great for multiple ApiResources. For example, my Spa application can call ApiResource1, ApiResource2, and ApiResource3 without any problems.

However, I have added a new ApiResource (i.e. ApiResource4) and I need to be able to call it from ApiResource1.  However, when I try to call

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

from ApiResource1, the access_token is null so the call fails.

How can I make a call from ApiResource1 to ApiResource2 using the logged in User's token?

Maybe a better way of asking is, how to I get the logged in users access_token from ApiResource1?

My SPA application is setup like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerOptions").GetValue<string>("BaseUrl");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerOptions").GetValue<string>("ClientId");
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerOptions").GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("ApiResource1");
                    options.Scope.Add("ApiResource2");
                    options.Scope.Add("ApiResource3");
                    options.Scope.Add("ApiResource4");
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                });
```

My ApiResources are setup like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer").GetValue<string>("BaseUrl");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.ApiName = _AppName;
                });
```

Comment: Have a look into extension grant delegation http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant.  It sounds like what you're after.  The other option is to *forward* the current user `access_token` by extracting it from the request Authorization header.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I was looking for. I will try to implement it tomorrow and make sure it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Brad how do I get the "userToken" mentioned in the doc you linked?  I have tried the following and all return null:             string userToken = _contextAccessor.HttpContext != null
                ? await _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetTokenAsync("id_token")
                    ?? await _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetTokenAsync("token")
                    ?? await _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.GetTokenAsync("access_token")

Comment: `GetTokenAsync()` only works with cookie authentication, not in an API using JWT.  The token is in the `Authorization` header.  It should be in `_context.HttpContext.Request.Headers`.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I didn't realize that GetTokenAsync only worked with cookie authentication. I did end up manually retrieving the token from the Auth header and that combined with your first comment solved the problem. Thank you! If you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` extension method only works with Cookie Authentication.  It will try to extract the token that is stored in the cookie.  This is not available when you have an API using JWT authentication.

You have two options.

1. **Use extension grant delegation** as explained in the Identity Server docs http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant.  This option is more complex to implement but it provides greater security.
2. **Extract and forward the JWT from the `Authorization` header**.  This option is as simple as getting the header from the Request and setting it on the headers of the `HttpClient` before making the API request.